# 404 - Not Found error while trying to access my new facebook app

Tags: facebook, templates, joomla, http-status-code-404

> 404 - Not Found The page you are trying to access does not exist. If
>   this error persists, please contact the website webmaster.

The above message appears when I attempt to access my new facebook app. Now please understand that I am new to web site and app development.

I purchased a Joomla template, uploaded those files to my web site and have NO probem viewing the template within the /site/ folder at my web site. I have followed all instructions from facebook and Joomla including watching tutorial videos typing in the file names exactly as instructed. On Firefox i first get the above 404 message. On IE i get the following message;

> Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security
>   certificate.

My site does not have a security certificate and I wasn't told I needed one, but is this the reason that my new facebook app won't display the template it's linked to on my web site?

Answer (score 0):

Starting just recently you will need to have an SSL cert to property host a facebook app.  The 404 might just be some latency with DNS settings needing to propagate thru the interwebs.